# The localhost page isn’t working on Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've not been working on Laravel 4 environment for about 2 years now. Now, I'm trying to help a friend out, and make some modification to the site. While trying to get the site up and running, I faced some errors.

---

Here is what I've did

- clone the project from repository
- composer update
- `chmod  -R 777` to public/ and vendor/ and bootstrap/
- Now, my file permission look like this

`-rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff      252 Oct 26 19:05 test.php -rwxr-xr-x   1 bheng  staff      519 Oct 26 19:05 server.php -rwxr-xr-x   1 bheng  staff     1913 Oct 26 19:05 readme.md drwxrwxrwx  17 bheng  staff      578 Oct 26 19:05 public -rwxr-xr-x   1 bheng  staff      566 Oct 26 19:05 phpunit.xml -rwxr-xr-x   1 bheng  staff     2062 Oct 26 19:05 error_log -rwxr-xr-x   1 bheng  staff     1027 Oct 26 19:05 composer.json drwxrwxrwx   5 bheng  staff      170 Oct 26 19:05 bootstrap -rwxr-xr-x   1 bheng  staff     2451 Oct 26 19:05 artisan -rw-r--r--   1 bheng  staff  1507527 Oct 26 19:05 app.zip drwxr-xr-x  15 bheng  staff      510 Oct 26 19:05 app -rwxr-xr-x   1 bheng  staff    26287 Oct 26 19:05 README -rwxr-xr-x   1 bheng  staff      145 Oct 26 19:05 CONTRIBUTING.md -rw-r--r--@  1 bheng  staff        0 Oct 26 19:12 Icon? -rw-r--r--   1 root   staff   105493 Oct 26 19:20 composer.lock drwxr-xr-x  28 bheng  staff      952 Oct 26 19:48 vendor`

- I am using MAMP in my Mac OS.
- I've tried look into my app.php
- I have set the correct URL as `'url' => 'http://localhost:8888',`
- Now when I go to the site I kept getting

> The localhost page isn’t working

[image]

---

**Update**

I've tried rename my `index.php` to `index_.php`

and add this content to my `index.php`

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Now, I got my php.ini page to load.

[image]

How do I take it from here?

Comment: enabling error reporting would be a good step

Comment: ....*yes*. specifically, check your php.ini

Comment: `phpinfo()` is **not** `php.ini`

Comment: check apache error logs ... and post them here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also apply correct write permissions to the `/app/storage` folder. This will show you where you have the error.

Comment: L4 doesn't have storage folder. I don't think

Comment: the storage folder is inside the app folder

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion, I don't see that error anymore.